# get value from header into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering is there a way get value from header directly on model.

```
# location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  puts request.header['key']
end
```

Let's pretend we have some value stored into header, into controller I use `request.headers['key']`. it worked but into model it's not

Comment: No, you'd have to pass the value from the controller to the model.

Comment: The model has no way to access request, sessions etc ... basically everything that is specific to the current request. Pass it as a parameter as Nate suggests

Answer (score 8):

As the comments point out, no, not directly. The `request` object is only available in the controller.

But since you have to instantiate your model in the controller anyway, there should be no problem in doing something like this:

```
# some_controller.rb
def some_action
  @location = Location.new(name: request.headers['key'])
  ...
end
```

Comment: Is this a good practice? To require, say a token, or anything else from the Headers from the controller? Is there a correct and safe way?

Comment: Sure. For example, Devise uses tokens from the request for password reset and such. Whether such tokens are passed to a method or a constructor is really irrelevant, as is their source, which could be parameters, cookies or request headers. As in any case where input comes from the user, it should be carefully sanitized.